# How to remove color from div when clicking another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have these 3 blue circles that serve a certain navigation purpose and should remain red when clicked. When you'd click another circle the initial red one should turn blue once again and the clicked circle would then also turn red.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>

a.link {width: 15px;height: 15px;background-color:blue;border-radius: 50px;position:absolute;}
a.link:hover {background-color: red}
a.link.active {background-color: red;}

.position1 {position: absolute;top: 100px;left: 50%;margin-left: -11.5px;}
.position2 {position: absolute;top: 200px;left: 50%;margin-left: -11.5px;}
.position3 {position: absolute;top: 300px;left: 50%;margin-left: -11.5px;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(function() {
               $('a.link').click(function() {
                   $('a.link').removeClass('active');
                   $(this).addClass('active');
               })
            });
         </script>

  <div class="position1"><a class="link" href="#"></a></div>
  <div class="position2"><a class="link" href="#"></a></div>
  <div class="position3"><a class="link" href="#"></a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ive done this in the past, same script, same way of working *but* this was by using text not custom div shapes.

I also want to make the second circle lit up red from the start by using the code 
`.eq(1).addClass('active');`

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/src6zf67/

Comment: It seems to be working, the fiddle just doesn't have jQuery included.

Comment: Your example does not include the jQuery library. Add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/src6zf67/4/

it has been working but you should onLOad jquery

Html:

```
  <div class="position1"><a class="link" href="#"></a></div>
  <div class="position2"><a class="link" href="#"></a></div>
  <div class="position3"><a class="link" href="#"></a></div>
```

js:

```
        $(function() {
           $('a.link').click(function() {
               $('a.link').removeClass('active');
               $(this).addClass('active');
           })
        });
```

Css :

```
a.link {width: 15px;height: 15px;background-color:blue;border-radius: 50px;position:absolute;}
a.link:hover {background-color: red}
a.link.active {background-color: red;}

.position1 {position: absolute;top: 100px;left: 50%;margin-left: -11.5px;}
.position2 {position: absolute;top: 200px;left: 50%;margin-left: -11.5px;}
.position3 {position: absolute;top: 300px;left: 50%;margin-left: -11.5px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps!! Good luck! [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/f60uwvus/3/) is it in motion.

```
// Grab all of the links and group them as a single jQuery object.
var $links = $('a.link'); 
// Create an event that triggers when any of the of the links are clicked on.
// Pass to it a data object with a single key $links
// so you can access the other
$links.on( 'click' , { $links : $links } , function ( event ) {
    // Remove the class active from all of the links.
    event.data.$links.removeClass('active');
    // Add the class active to the link we clicked on.
    $( event.target ).addClass( 'active' );
} );
```